# How to get a form control valueChanges value before subscription?

Tags: angular, observable, form-control

Hi I have a parent form control and a child component. The child component is not displayed until the parent form control has changed, e.g.:

```
<div *ngIf="parentControlChanged">
  <ChildComponent [value]="parentChanged$ | async"></ChildComponent>
</div>
```

As you can see, the child component is using an `async` pipe to get the value from the parent control (here `parentControlChanged` is a boolean state to indicate the parent control is first changed and `parentChanged$` is just a pipe of the parentControl.valueChanges with some additional side-effects unrelated to this question).

The issue is the child component is not displayed until the parent control has changed, and hence not subscribed to the `valueChanges` yet, and hence not getting the changed value of the parent control. Otherwise, the child component is getting every subsequent change value of the parent control once it is displayed.

So is there a way for the child component to get the latest/current value of the parent control once it subscribes to the `valueChanges` with `async` pipe just like subscribing to a `BehaviorSubject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something else is already subscribed to `parentChanged$` then, in addition to the side effects you didn't go into, pipe `shareReplay(1)` at the end of it.

Then, as long as `parentChanged$` is already subscribed to, when the child component or anything else subscribes to it, it will initially get the last-emitted value *and* any side effects will still be executed once, not once per subscriber.

If `parentChanged$` isn't already subscribed to then you either have to always subscribe and do the above, or change to a pattern where you do something like changing `xyz.valueChanges` to `concat(defer(() => of(xyz.value)), xyz.valueChanges)` so that when you subscribe, it starts with the initial value you want to send, *then* sends changes.

Comment: Very nice, the `defer` trick solved it.